# Is it better to set data in class with data class or with setters in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

So I am working with custom components in android and i was looking for a way to set attributes in the component programmatically and i came across doing that either with data class or setters and getters , but each have its draw backs so I have been searching what is the best practice to be taken in such case or should I just use both approaches

Comment: *but each have its draw backs* means you will have to decide wich of them is most suitable for your project or situation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A data structure like a data class gives you more control - you can require every parameter to be set explicitly (e.g. through the constructor with no default values), or use builder functions if you only require certain combinations of parameters to be set together. You can even do validation and default value logic through that construction process, to make sure that every config object is valid and has appropriate values.

And because they're objects, you can create some standard instances of them, like a `Default` config that certain settings, or another config that sets things up a different way. You could use those for convenience (it's a bunch of settings for a particular use-case, ready to go) or even restrict the allowed configs to one of those presets. Makes testing easier too! Since you can easily set up your component exactly the way it needs to be.

Having a single object for those properties also makes it easier to serialise and deserialise your state, since you just need to store one object, and then apply it when it's recreated. Handy if you need to persist those settings, either while your app is in the background, or just storing them in a database etc.

---

The question is really, do you need it? Is it overcomplicating something that only needs a few independent properties? Are the properties changed often enough that creating a new state object becomes a pain, or expensive? Having a data structure like this enables you to define and enforce some rules, which can be really helpful, but there are also times where that's more of a burden than a help. It's really a call you have to make, and the best way to learn is trying both and seeing when each does or doesn't work.

What I will say is that Android's recommended architecture [includes UI state objects](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/stateholders), which basically involves defining an object with all the necessary properties to describe your UI's whole state. This is so instead of having to juggle a bunch of properties updating independently, and working out how they affect each other, you can just pass an entire, validated state, and handle that as a whole. It's much easier to reason about, especially in the modern app style which is built more around reacting to async events as and when they happen.